# if cell is greater or less than the sum of the range of cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, conditional-formatting

[image]

I've looked around for an answer to this without success.

I have a spreadsheet where I need the "18" change and be highlighted as green if the sum of the next 4 columns with a check is greater than 18.
Stay in yellow if equal to the sum, and red if under.

Tried to use `=SUM(Col1:Col4)`, and `=SUM(S642,T642,U642,V642)` but it is not working..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The table below assumes that the `18` is in cell `A1` and the columns to SUM are columns `B` to `E`.  You can adapt this to match your own spreadsheet.

| Color | Custom Formula |
| --- | --- |
| Green | `=SUM(B1:E1)>A1` |
| Yellow | `=SUM(B1:E1)=A1` |
| Red | `=SUM(B1:E1)<A1` |